# JQuery Validator - Success function not being called on valid submission

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am using JQuery validator from: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

I have written the JQuery that I need which validates correctly however the last part of my submit function is not working correctly.

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
    rules: {
        email_options_name: {
            required: true
        },
        email_options_company: {
            required: true
        },
        email_options_country: {
            required: true
        },
        email_option_email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        check_options: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 1
        }
    },      
});

$("#commentForm").submit(function(){

    var valid = $("#commentForm").valid();
    if (valid) {
                $.post('scripts/process_email_initial_form.php',$(this).serialize(), function(o) {
                    location.reload();
                }, 'json');
            } else {
                $('.full-error').show();
            }

                return false;
});

$.extend($.validator.messages, {
            required: "!",
            email: "!"
});
```

}

When the submit is valid the script `process_email_initial_form.php` is called and processes correctly (from looking into firebug) and if not the div does show. The problem is that when the script has finished running `location.reload();` does not call. Ideally I wanted to direct to a success page but this didn't work either.

I tried to put a php header function at the end of `process_email_initial_form.php` but this does not work either.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).  **Use the `submitHandler` callback function.**  It's where you put your `ajax`.  Your external `submit` handler is screwing up the built-in submit handler of the plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), the submitHandler callback is 'The right place to submit a form via Ajax after it validated.'

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
    rules: {
        // your rules here
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
       // example below uses the 'form' plugin
       // http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#api
       $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            success: function(){
                window.location.href="newPage.php"
            }
       });
    }      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only checked whether the form is valid or not. By checking this will return boolean value only, it does not set error messages. You need to assing error to $('.full-error') before showing it.

Try

```
$("#commentForm").validate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use `done` event?

```
$.post(
    'scripts/process_email_initial_form.php',
    $(this).serialize(), 
    function(o) {
       console.log('success');
    },
    'json'
).done(function(o){
    window.location.replace("success.php");
});
```

PHP header in your ajax page won't redirect your current page to success page. It will just make your ajax page redirect to the header defined.

Instead of using `window.location.replace` you can try submit the form using jquery.

```
$("#commentForm").submit(function(){
    var valid = $("#commentForm").valid();
    if (valid) {
        $.post(
        'scripts/process_email_initial_form.php',
        $(this).serialize(),
        function(o) {
            console.log('success');
        },
        'json')
        .done(function(o) {
            $(this).attr('action', 'success.php');
            return true;
        });
    } else {
        $('.full-error').show();
        return false;
    }
});
```

OR

```
$("#commentForm").submit(function(){
    var valid = $("#commentForm").valid();
    if (valid) {
        $.post(
        'scripts/process_email_initial_form.php',
        $(this).serialize(),
        function(o) {
            $(this).attr('action', 'success.php');
            return true;
        },
        'json');
    } else {
        $('.full-error').show();
        return false;
    }
});
```